# Regular Expression in Java for validating username

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm trying the username chains in Java with following rules:

- Length >=3
- Valid characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, points, dashes and underscores.

Could someone help me with the regular expression?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{3,}$
```

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{3,} is more accurate as he wants to include "points dashes and underscores". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028642/regular-expression-for-letters-numbers-and

Comment: @TheCapn: I fixed it as you were writing your comment.  :-)

Comment: You should add start `^` and end-of-string `$` anchors for validation regexes like these (although the Java `.matches()` method does do this implicitly).

Answer (score 5):

Sarkiroka solution is right, but forgot the dash and the point should be escaped.

You should add as \ to escape it, but mind that in Java the backslash is itself used to escape, so if you are writing the regex in a java file, you should write

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\._\\-]{3,}";
```

Note the double back slashes.

Comment: No need to escape `.`, and probably no need to escape `-` either since it's last in the class (but I'm unsure how Java handles this).

Answer (score 4):

BTW, if there is an extra requirement: the starting letter of the username must be a character, you can write

```
try {
    if (subjectString.matches("\\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-._]{3,}\\b")) {
        // Successful match 

    } else {
        // No match 

    }
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Invalid regex 

}
```

Based on an example [here](http://tools.twainscanning.com/getmyregex).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
    username.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9.\\-_]{3,}")
```

Comment: I don't think you have to escape the .-_ characters if they're in the [] but other than that it looks fine, though you should've commented on Richie's answer before posting your own.

Comment: The dash must be escaped, but it doesn't matter for the dot.