# Java Regex matcher validation

Tags: java, regex

I already Read the Post on [Regular Expression in Java for validating username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782437/regular-expresion-in-java-for-validating-username)

I tried to do it myself. with JAVA 1.7

```
String value="12345_-6zA";
Boolean result= value.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]");
System.out.println(result);
```

I also Tried

```
String value="12345a";
Boolean result= value.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]")
System.out.println(result);
```

But both gives me result "False" , the String value only contained the char the regex said. I cant figure out why it returned false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing quantifier `+` which would make sure to match 1 or of those characters in your character class:

Use this:

```
boolean result = value.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+");
```

Or even better:

```
boolean result = value.matches("[\\w-]+");
```

Since `\w` is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`