# Prevent malicious input to execute when script called

Tags: java, unix

I need to call a Unix script in my Java code, wait for it to execute, and get the output. The script will do a 'find', and user will  provide the directory he wants the 'find' to look in

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c",
                              runnerScript.getAbsolutePath() + " " + Param1 };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Problem is : How can I prevent one to type `' && rm -rf *'` or `' / -exec rm..'` ?

I have an idea like check if the directory exist on the server, or use a method like `isLetterOrDigit()`, but I want to know if a safer way exists.
I know for Sql Query I can use PreparedStatement to work around this problem. Is there something similar when calling a script?

Comment: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `/bin/sh -c` for this?

Comment: well my script could run on Hp-Ux,Solaris,Aix and several linux distros. i want to be sure it's executed with the shell i want

Comment: The drawback of that is that passing an uncontrolled string to `bash -c` for it to execute is inherently less safe than invoking your script and passing a parameter into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is executable, I believe you should be able to construct your command like this:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { runnerScript.getAbsolutePath(), Param1 };
```

This way, you are calling your script, and just passing it the parameter; rather than calling `bash -c` and passing it a string to execute, which is inherently unsafe.

To specify which shell your script should run in, you can put `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the script.

Comment: Will your method protect from this? the script will do `find $1 ..`  $1 is  `String Param1=" \"/foo/bar\" -exec rm {};\\ # ";` it will be `find  "/foo/bar" -exec rm {};\ #`

Comment: I guess that depends on what your script does.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to `ProcessBuilder` for a similar purpose.

Refer to : [How to sanitize user input used in Runtime.exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972123/how-to-sanitize-user-input-used-in-runtime-exec)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-l");
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    System.out.println("Executed");
    while (p.isAlive())
    {}
    InputStream s = p.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       builder.append(line);
       builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```