# Make sure username contains only: A-Z, a-z, ., _, -, 0-9 (no comma) PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regular expression for letters, numbers and - _](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028642/regular-expression-for-letters-numbers-and)

I am creating a signup form in PHP and need to ensure that user's usernames don't contain unwanted characters. Is there anyway I can create a function that returns true for `A-Z a-z 0-9 - . _`.

Also I do not want the user's emails to be from yahoo as for some reason they reject the confirmation emails sent. Along with `__FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL__`what would I need to add?

PS: is there anything wrong with the characters I have mentioned above? I have noted that gmail doesn't allow `-_` only . and YouTube only alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: please allow me to chose what ever user-name i want,not arbitrarily restrict me. Thanks.

Comment: @Dragon What do you want to know my site? :)

Comment: @MuqMan I want all sites to stop imposing meaningless restrictions.

Comment: @mario, its not a duplicate because i want a . as well ;) and I __never__ found that post!

Comment: @MuqMan: That happens to be included. If you couldn't be bothered to make such a trivial addition, then you're wrong on Stackoverflow. And there many more duplicates. Objectively too little search effort.

Comment: @mario im sure you can tell that i am not too frequent to SO, also i _did_ google it, plus I don't know the rules of prey_match! Sorry if this seems against your terms!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edited to use \w instead of a-zA-Z0-9_

```
if(preg_match("/[^\w-.]/", $user)){
    // invalid character
}
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || strstr($email,'@yahoo.com')) {
    // either invalid email, or it contains in @yahoo.com
}
```

Comment: Could be shortened to `[^\w.-]`.

Comment: wait i also do want the _ ? would that work and does \w extend to numbers? w sounds like it represents words

Comment: \w finds [a-z][A-Z][0-9] and the underscore [_].  You can replace the first line with `if(preg_match("/[^\w-.?]/", $user)){`

Comment: `and added '?' to valid username character` what does that mean? Thanks anyway. I've marked your answer as answer! It helps a lot!

Comment: I thought your original comment said you wanted the ? allowed also. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(preg_match("/[^-A-Za-z0-9._ ]/", $userName)){
    // there are one or more of the forbidden characters (the set of which is unknown)
}
```

Comment: wait $email will be $user for me right? $email needs to be escaped from @yahoo.com

Comment: @zerkms - wouldn't that eval to false? Question was for eval to true if chars are present.

Comment: @zerkms um where does the `^` go?

Comment: @circusdei: please test your code on any invalid input, say `      a` (spaces followed by `a` char)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

    // The validator class

    class Validator
    {
        public function isValidUsername($username)
        {
            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+$/', $username)) {
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function isYahooMail($mail) {
            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@yahoo.com$/', $mail)) {
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    // The way to use this class

    $username = "otporan_123";
    $email = "otporan@gmail.com";

    $badUsername = "otporan*bad";
    $yahooEmail = "otporan@yahoo.com";

    $validator = new Validator();

    var_export($validator->isValidUsername($username));
    echo "<br />";

    var_export($validator->isValidUsername($badUsername));
    echo "<br />";

    var_export($validator->isYahooMail($email));
    echo "<br />";

    var_export($validator->isYahooMail($yahooEmail));
    echo "<br />";  

?>
```

This code would return:
true
false
false
true

This is a class, but you can see whats going on in methods and write your own functions if you like procedural code :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: great! I'll try it out! Looks like you're introducing me to classes and OOP ;)

Comment: I wanted to mark both as answers but right now i am not doing OOP much :) srry not to give you the full points but I still plus1d your answer (not google plus ;))

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!preg_match('/\w\-/', $username) {
    //throw error 
}
```

Comment: This matches any word-char followed by a hyphen. Clearly not desired.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but like they said, it doesn't work. :(