# Use preg_match to return true if $var includes only (A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and -)

Tags: php, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [regular expression for letters, numbers and - _](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028642/regular-expression-for-letters-numbers-and)

I would like to return true if the $var only includes (**A-Z**, **a-z**, **0-9** and **-**)

Something like: (this preg_match is to check if $var is mail, but I need the above)

```
if (!preg_match("/^[-!#$%&\'*+\\.\/0-9=?A-Z^_`{|}~]+@([-0-9A-Z]+\.)+([0-9A-Z]){2,4}$/i", $var))
    return false;
return true;
```

Any ideas? Im new with preg_match.

Comment: Is this an email address? if so dont use a regular expression to check email addresses use the php filters. looks like email but only includes (A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and -) is weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this preg_match with the code you provided:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9-]+$/i", $var)
```

It will match if `$var` includes only *(A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and -)* and is at least 1 character long. If you want to match also empty strings turn the `+` in a `*`.

Comment: will it  return true or  false ?

Comment: @Phoenix: preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred. ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php )