# regex to only include a-z A-Z 0-9 dashes and underscores

Tags: php, regex

I have searched within SO and found out several regular expressions to be used to include ONLY THESE `a-z A-Z 0-9 - _`. So far what I have tried was this one, `/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s`. What this actually did was it did not exclude `brackets {} []` and `parenthesis ()`. I am not very experienced with `regex`, heck I don't fully fathom the whole meaning, structure/format of it so can somebody provide me the exact `regex` which I am looking for? Thanks for the time.

Comment: Another `-1` for profanity. Being new to something does not exempt you from doing a [bit of research](http://regexp.info/).

Comment: Yeah, thank you captain obvious.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regular expression for letters, numbers and -](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3028642)

Comment: @mario - You probably mean 'thoroughness'? 'Profanity' is not the noun of 'being profound'.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is :

```
  ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}$
```

Will check Any word of at least one letter, number , _ or -

[Here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php) is the tutorial for basic REGEX.

Comment: Remember `{1,}` is just `+`

Comment: It is up to him , how he want to use regex. i have explained only for 1 limit.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

`/^[\w\-]+$/`