# regular expression for letters, numbers and - _ form domain validation

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble for checking combination for letter and number, for domain validation which is the TLD not include on input form. And for this combination:

- letters(upper or lowercase)
- numbers(0-9)
- underscore (_)
- dash (-)
- point (.)
- no spaces! or other characters

and for examples:

- "total23"  = OK
- "total-23" = OK
- "total_23" = OK
- "total-" = not OK
- "total_" = not OK
- "total " = not OK
- "total@" = not OK

I've read this tutorial, but still haven't found the answer for my case.
[regular expression for letters, numbers and - _](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028642/regular-expression-for-letters-numbers-and)

Comment: This is a good resource to fool around with regular expressions and get a hand to it. 


    https://regexr.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assume your "TLD" contains "allowed characters", and must start and end with a letter or digit:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+([._-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```